# Magento 2 - Add the Sidebar Order Summary on Customer Account Create

Tags: magento2, customer-account, sidebar, order-summary

On Magento 2.x I'd like to display the `Order Summary` via the sidebar on the page `customer/account/create`. You can find this sidebar on `Checkout/#shipping` page usually. Is it even possible?

I tried to create a `customer_account_create.xml` file in `app/design/frontend/<Vendorname>/<theme>/Magento_Customer/layout/` containing the following (*but with no success so far - nothing changed*):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <!-- I added those 3 items ... -->
    <update handle="checkout_cart_sidebar_item_renderers"/>
    <update handle="checkout_cart_sidebar_item_price_renderers"/>
    <update handle="checkout_cart_sidebar_total_renderers"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.components">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Components" name="customer_account_create_head_components" template="Magento_Customer::js/components.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Register" name="customer_form_register" template="Magento_Customer::form/register.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="attribute_data" xsi:type="object">Magento\Customer\Block\DataProviders\AddressAttributeData</argument>
                </arguments>
                <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
                <container name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" label="Form Fields Before" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="customer-form-before"/>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="registerSubmitButton" xsi:type="string">.action.submit</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="form_additional_info_customer" template="Magento_Customer::additionalinfocustomer.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <!-- ... and this sidebar block, but it is not displaying actually -->
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" name="minicart" as="minicart" after="logo" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/minicart.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="types" xsi:type="array"/>
                        <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="minicart_content" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart</item>
                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/content</item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="subtotal.container" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">subtotalContainer</item>
                                        </item>
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="subtotal" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/minicart/subtotal</item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="extra_info" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">extraInfo</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                    <item name="promotion" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">promotion</item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
                <container name="minicart.addons" label="Mini-cart promotion block"/>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up editing the `app/design/frontend/<Vendorname>/<theme>/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_create.xml`

With the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="checkout_cart_item_renderers"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart" name="checkout.cart" template="Magento_Checkout::cart.phtml" cacheable="false">
                <container name="checkout.cart.items" as="with-items" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="modal-custom opc-sidebar opc-summary-wrapper custom-slide">
                    <container name="checkout.cart.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="cart-container" before="-">                      
                        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Grid" name="checkout.cart.form" as="cart-items" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/form.phtml" after="customer_form_register">
                            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers" as="renderer.list"/>
                            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text\ListText" name="checkout.cart.order.actions"/>
                        </block>
                        <container name="checkout.cart.widget" as="checkout_cart_widget" label="Shopping Cart Items After"/>
                    </container>
                </container>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Not exactly the same sidebar as the `Checkout/#shipping` page, but good enough for the needs I had...